# MySQL 8.0 memory usage continuously growing

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I have installed MySQL 8.0.29 on a dedicated server with 16 vCores and 60 GB RAM but the memory usage is still growing. I restarted the mysql service 2 months ago and it takes about 91% RAM now:
[image]

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           57Gi        51Gi       511Mi       2.0Mi       5.5Gi       5.3Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

my configuration is:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log

bind-address = 10.10.0.2
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 259200
binlog_do_db = dbname

skip_name_resolve = 1
innodb_dedicated_server = 1
max_allowed_packet = 536870912
max_connections = 1000
join_buffer_size = 1048576
```

mysqltuner.pl outputs:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 2.0.11
     * Jean-Marie Renouard <jmrenouard@gmail.com>
     * Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.29-21
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log (300K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 2313 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 1 error(s).
[--] 143 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 1) 2022-12-17T05:00:49.782964Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29-21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 2) 2022-12-17T05:00:49.782926Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 3) 2022-12-07T05:25:48.429925Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29-21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 4) 2022-12-07T05:25:48.429905Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 5) 2022-11-16T05:45:33.898403Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 6) 2022-11-16T05:45:33.896585Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29-21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 7) 2022-10-19T12:55:01.812148Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29-21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 8) 2022-10-19T12:55:01.811935Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 9) 2022-10-19T12:43:10.091727Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29-21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 10) 2022-10-19T12:43:10.091690Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
[--] 16 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 1) 2022-12-17T04:53:22.580264Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29-21)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 2) 2022-12-07T05:24:48.272111Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29-21)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 3) 2022-11-16T05:43:23.710144Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29-21)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 4) 2022-10-15T23:45:59.932949Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29-21)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 5) 2022-08-29T18:05:15.236277Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29-21)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '21', Revision 'c59f87d2854'.
[--] 6) 2022-08-29T16:07:59.235204Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-20)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '20', Revision 'fd4b5a776a6'.
[--] 7) 2022-08-05T12:31:06.292042Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-20)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '20', Revision 'fd4b5a776a6'.
[--] 8) 2022-07-29T13:58:25.716035Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-20)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '20', Revision 'fd4b5a776a6'.
[--] 9) 2022-07-28T19:27:27.158294Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-20)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '20', Revision 'fd4b5a776a6'.
[--] 10) 2022-07-27T21:26:21.431830Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-20)  Percona Server (GPL), Release '20', Revision 'fd4b5a776a6'.
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 15.9G (Tables: 604)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 1
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Views Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Triggers Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Routines Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to unsupported feature for MySQL 8
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 53d 5h 22m 49s (7B q [1K qps], 94M conn, TX: 57240G, RX: 6285G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 57.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 547.0G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 44.0G global + 514.6M per thread (1000 max threads)
[--] Performance_schema Max memory usage: 400M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 192.7G (335.17% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 547.0G (951.48% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/7B)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 29% (295/1000)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00% (1/94397108)
[--] Query cache has been removed since MySQL 8.0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (11M temp sorts / 2B sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 723947
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (285K on disk / 412M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (803K created / 94M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (14B hits / 14B requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (945)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (6/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (131 immediate / 131 locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 98.13% (41213195 Memory / 41998131 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by Performance_schema: 400.6M
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] MyISAM Metrics are disabled since MySQL 8.0.
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 44.0G / 15.9G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (75%): 1.0G * 33 / 44.0G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 352 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (8303978165000 hits / 8303978910176 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 96.33% (8325309995 hits / 8642424121 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (5 waits / 317114126 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Check warning line(s) in /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Check error line(s) in /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Run ALTER TABLE ... FORCE or OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
      ALTER TABLE `magento`.`mageplaza_smtp_log` FORCE; -- can free 2024 MiB
    Total freed space after defragmentation : 2024 MiB
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Buffer Key MyISAM set to 0, no MyISAM table detected
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 1.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    key_buffer_size=0
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=341M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=44)
```

mysql status:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Max_used_connections';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| Max_used_connections | 295   |
+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` like 'Threads_%';
+-------------------+--------+
| Variable_name     | Value  |
+-------------------+--------+
| Threads_cached    | 10     |
| Threads_connected | 47     |
| Threads_created   | 804042 |
| Threads_running   | 8      |
+-------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For variables and full output of show status command please look at https://gist.github.com/macdar/b044e725438ff574ff3a445c543be39d

Is something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

No problem.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` was probably automatically set to 70-80% or RAM.  Then, as mysqld was running, it gradually grew that cache up to that max.  It looks like memory is about at the max, so it may flatten out over the next few days.

If you want further analysis, please provide all of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES`.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: Thank you. I added output of these commands here https://gist.github.com/macdar/b044e725438ff574ff3a445c543be39d

Comment: It is already at 95% of the total memory now, so IMO something is not right.

Answer (score 0):

max_allowed_packet at 536,870,912 is huge.

It could be related to these values:

```
[--] Total buffers: 44.0G global + 514.6M per thread (1000 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 547.0G (951.48% of installed RAM)
```

I would go back to a lower value:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html

I would also try to catch inefficient queries:

```
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries              = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time               = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Comment: MySQL official documentation mentions that "It is safe to increase the value of this variable because the extra memory is allocated only when needed. For example, mysqld allocates more memory only when you issue a long query or when mysqld must return a large result row. The small default value of the variable is a precaution to catch incorrect packets between the client and server and also to ensure that you do not run out of memory by using large packets accidentally." so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When setting `log-queries-no-using-indexes` is enabled, recommend enabling [sysvar_min_examined_row_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_min_examined_row_limit) to between 100 and 10000 (probably starting high) to ensure the very small tables without indexes don't flood the slow query log.

Comment: I say that `log-queries-not-using-indexes` is virtually useless -- Any query that "needs" and index will be "slow" anyway.  Any table that is "tiny" won't be helped by an index.  (The exception is when you have very little data, but expect the tables to grow.)